# Proof of probability that mean is in bootstrap confidence interval

Tags: bootstrap, proof

Suppose $P$ is our true probability distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, and we have samples $X_1,\cdots,X_n$. Suppose also that we bootstrap sample with replacement. Let $P_n$ be our bootstrap distribution.

We choose $R_n$ such that:
$$
P_n \left(\vert\bar{X}_n^*-\bar{X}_n\vert \leq \frac{R_n}{\sqrt{n}}\right) = 1-\alpha
$$

Define 
$$
C_n^* = \left(\bar X_n-\frac{R_n}{\sqrt n},\bar X_n+\frac{R_n}{\sqrt n} \right).
$$

I would like to show that
$$
P^{\mathbb{N}}(\mu\in C_n ^*)\rightarrow 1-\alpha
$$

where $P^{\mathbb{N}}=\lim P_n$

However, I have no idea where to start.

Comment: I suppose you would like to show it because it is a homework or take-home test problem?

Comment: yes, I am struggling to understand my bootstrapping works

Comment: I have my doubts about this.  All that is specified about the population distribution is that the first two moments exist.  There are many ways to generate bootstrap confidenc intervals and none of them are exact.  Are you doing the actual bootstrap or the Monte Carlo approximation to it? I am not sure what $R_n$ is and you first say that you get an exact result for finite n but later you change notation and look at an asymptotic result.

Comment: Here the bootstrap samples are vectors of length $n$, and elements chosen uniformly at random from the $X_i$'s with replacement - I am not doing Monte Carlo. $R_n$ is the number such that the given inequality is true, and there is no exact result that I am quoting.